# Like search with special chrachter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have table `tbl_Main`

```
AS_ID   KWD
1       Man,Businessman,[Business],Office,confidence,arms crossed,
2       Man,Businessman,Business,[Office],laptop,"corridor",waiting,
3       man,business,mobile phone,[mobile],"phone",
```

If I search for `[office]` with like search I didn't get any result.

I am using the following query

```
select * from tbl_main where KWD like '%,[Office],%'
```

Please help me to solve this query.Thanks

Comment: You're trying to query AS_ID which doesn't have Office. Try querying KWD for Office.

Comment: @Gitz I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` and `]` are used for pattern matching (similar to regex) when using `LIKE` in SQL Server, so what you are actually searching for is

```
WHERE   KWD LIKE '%,O,%'
OR      KWD LIKE '%,f,%'
OR      KWD LIKE '%,i,%'
OR      KWD LIKE '%,c,%'
OR      KWD LIKE '%,e,%'
```

You need to escape your brackets, e.g:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES
            (1, 'Man,Businessman,[Business],Office,confidence,arms crossed,'),
            (2, 'Man,Businessman,Business,[Office],laptop,"corridor",waiting,'),
            (3, 'man,business,mobile phone,[mobile],"phone",')
        ) t (AS_ID, KWD)
WHERE   KWD like '%,\[Office\],%' ESCAPE '\';
```

**ADDENDUM**

For what it is worth you should normalise your data, instead of storing a delimited list, use a separate relation table with a foreign key back to `tbl_main`, e.g.

```
AS_ID   Keyword
-----------------------
1       Man
1       Businessman
1       [Business]
1       Office
1       confidence
1       arms crossed
```

Now you have a simple query, that is able to leverage the use of indexes if they exist:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ASKeyword
WHERE   Keyword = '[Office]';
```

Comment: "phone" should work as normal -- `WHERE   KWD like '%,"PHONE",%'`

Comment: Thanks for your help @GarethD :)

Comment: I am using perimeter between the like search query like `'%,\['+@kwd +'\],%' ESCAPE '\'` but didn't get any result. @GarethD

Comment: You should replace the special characters in the parameter - `WHERE   KWD LIKE '%,' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Kwd, '\', '\\'), ']', '\]'), '[', '\[') + ',%' ESCAPE '\'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from tbl_main where KWD like '%,[Office],%'
```

Comment: Using the same query but didn't get any result